# How to convert a 187.5 string to number and insert in Decimal(3,1) column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Problem : I need to convert a string value "187,5" and insert into a data type DECIMAL(3,1)

I have a mysql table called "betygpoang" with a "poang" field and the datatype is set to DECIMAL(3,1) and a "betyg" table with a "meritvarde" field and the datatype is set to DECIMAL(3,1) here as well, and Im using asp classic.

I sum and get a decimal value from "poang" that I need to update "meritvarde" with in the "betyg" table, the problem is that the sum value I get back is a text string "187,5" with a comma(,) even if it is a point(.) in the database.

So I have to convert "187,5" to "187.5" a proper decimal value to be able to insert it to my db.

I select and sum it, and update it like this.

```
sql = "SELECT sum(poang) FROM betygpoang"
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
meritvarde=CDbl(rs19("sum(poang)"))
meritvarde=replace(meritvarde,",",".")

sql= "UPDATE betyg SET meritvarde = "& meritvarde;"
conn.Execute (sql)
```

So here is "meritvarde" "187.5" but still a string. And with this I get an error saying `"Out of range value for column 'meritvarde'"` so its not the right data type since its a string I guess.

But how can I convert it to be the right format?
If I use CINT then it rounds it up to 188.

Comment: Have you tried setting that value explicitly (through using the SQL query in the MySQL shell or some equivalent) to check whether this is possible after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECIMAL(3,1) -> Max is 99.9
if you want to store 187.5 , change to DECIMAL(4,1) -> Max is 999.9

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that haha, as soon as you write a question, you find the answer ;-)